# Rails - alias_method_chain with a 'attribute=' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alias-method-chain

I'd like to 'add on' some code on a model's method via a module, when it is included. I think I should use alias_method_chain, but I don't know how to use it, since my 'aliased method' is one of those methods ending on the '=' sign:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def foo=(value)
    ... do stuff with value
  end

end
```

So this is what my module looks right now:

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    base.class_eval do

      alias_method_chain 'foo=', :bar

    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def foo=_with_bar(value) # ERROR HERE
      ... do more stuff with value
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error on the function definition. How do get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`alias_method_chain` is a simple, two-line method:

```
def alias_method_chain( target, feature )
  alias_method "#{target}_without_#{feature}", target
  alias_method target, "#{target}_with_#{feature}"
end
```

I think the answer you want is to simply make the two `alias_method` calls yourself in this case:

```
alias_method :foo_without_bar=, :foo=
alias_method :foo=, :foo_with_bar=
```

And you would define your method like so:

```
def foo_with_bar=(value)
  ...
end
```

Ruby symbols process the trailing `=` and `?` of method names without a problem.

Comment: alias_method_chain is not a simple two-line method (any more?), and it should handle the = sign as expected (that is, creating foo_with_bar= and foo_without_bar=)